# HTML5 canvas get screenshot of a div is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to capture a div into an image using html5 canvas. Where I've a background image of that div so when trying to download the image in jpeg it is download without the background image. I'm sure I've that image in my domain so no way to break the same origin rule

***HTML***

```
<div id="testdiv" style="background:(path/to/image) no-repat">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//var testdiv = document.getElementById("testdiv");
    html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(myImage);
        }
    });
});
```

Why it's now drawing the background image of the div on canvas?

Any help? Thanks

Comment: No error in console?

Comment: No error there in console. I'm using Chrome

Comment: No it is absolute path of the image..

Answer (score -1):

You have to set css height to your div#testdiv like :

```
<div id="testdiv" style="background:(path/to/image) no-repeat; height:700px"></div>
```